# Basic question regarding correction for multiple comparisons

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

Thank you very much for your time and expertise. I have a pretty basic problem at hand. I have a dataset comprised of staff response times (SRT) to certain accidents on two units (A and B).

I am interested in knowing if there is a difference in SRT between units, between the types of accidents (X and Y) that occurred, and between whether or not an audio alarm preceded the accident.

1. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test (due to the non-normality of data) comparing SRT on Unit A and SRT on Unit B, generating p-value H.
2. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test comparing SRT for accident X and SRT for accident Y, generating p-value I.
3. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test comparing SRT without alarm and SRT with alarm, generating p-value J.
4. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test comparing SRT on Unit A and SRT on Unit B (for accident X exclusively), generating p-value K.
5. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test comparing SRT without alarm and SRT with alarm (on Unit A exclusively), generating p-value L.
6. I've conducted a Wilcoxon test comparing SRT without alarm and SRT with alarm (on Unit B exclusively), generating p-value M.

I am interested in correcting for multiple comparisons, since 6 statistical tests have been done for the same dataset. I plan to use the Holm-Bonferroni method using R.

My question is as follows: should I correct all my calculated p-values for multiple comparisons (i.e p-values H through M)? Or should I only correct the p-values I - J - K for multiple comparisons, and leave the other p-values as they are? Or is there something else that I should be doing? Thank you.